2d numpy indexing by another array
So, I have a 2d array
a.shape
(1050, 21)

And a 1d array
b.shape
(1050,)

I'm looking for a way (other than iterating) to produce 1d array (let's call it "c") from "a" so that c[x] = a[x, b[x]]

Assuming this example:
np.random.seed(0)

a = np.random.random((1050, 21))
b = np.random.randint(0, 21, a.shape[0])

expected = np.array([a[i, b[i]] for i in range(len(a))])

You can use advanced indexing:
c = a[np.arange(len(a)), b]

Or take_along_axis:
c = np.take_along_axis(a, b[:, None], axis=1)[:, 0]

Validation:
np.allclose(expected, c)
# True

timings:
# np.array([a[i, b[i]] for i in range(len(a))])
268 µs ± 8.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

# a[np.arange(len(a)), b]
8.48 µs ± 1.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

# np.take_along_axis(a, b[:, None], axis=1)[:, 0]
13.3 µs ± 889 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

